# Attempted to load class "DoctrineCacheBundle" from namespace "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle"

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Can anyone help me, guys? Every time I run the command `php bin/console server:run` this error occurs:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to
> load class "DoctrineCacheBundle" from namespace
> "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle". Did you forget a "use"
> statement for another namespace? in C:\Users\XX-2\Desktop\React
> Projects\test_project\src\Kernel.php:23

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Possible this is because of update doctrine bundle. Remove this line `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],` from `bundles.php`, it works for me.

Comment: You saved my life! Haha! It works fine for me perfectly. Appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue installing the missing dependency:

`composer require doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle`

Comment: Fix name compose to composer, pls

Comment: Ops, my bad! Done, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Old question and already answered but in my case it was because of the repository files were created with an earlier symfony version.

Fixed by changing:

```
Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface
```

For:

```
Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry
```